# Is Middleware required to use web sockets in React Redux Application

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement a socket based react(redux) application. the socket events has to be dispatched to the store so the reducers would act upon it. 
Now the way I think is keep the store in one file and refer to that from Socket events File and whenever socket messages are received then emit an event to store via socket.dispatch

in store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
let store = createStore(appStore);
export default store
```

in SocketJs file

```
   import store from './store';
   import io from socketio.client;

   let Socket = {
      createSocketIoConnection = function(){
        var socket = io(url, {reconnection: false, transports: ['websocket']});
        socket.on('data', this.emitToStore);  

      },
      emitToStore: function(data){
        store.dispatch();
      }

   }
```

the same store is used in main file ad passed as props to Provider

```
import store from './store';
<Provider store={store}>
  <App> ...
</Provider>
```

Here I am not using any middleware. Is this a right approach.

Comment: Looks fine, but architectural decisions don't have single answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't *have* to use middleware, but middleware is the *right* place to put this kind of behavior.  In fact, there's already [many existing websocket middlewares you can use](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware-sockets-adapters.md#websockets).

Comment: I had already gone through the link you gave and also the redux documentation page. I am not getting whats the use of middleware here. Thanks for reply.. it seems kind of complicating a simple behavior in this use case. The middleware examples given by redux site (logger, crash reporting) allows the middle ware function to be called on all the actions fired across the app but in my case the socket event handler dont have to act like that. its just like a simple event emitter to store. any thoughts ?

Comment: Middleware act as a loophole where you can execute asynchronous code and still interact with the store. That makes them an ideal place to hold persistent connections like websockets. You can send a message to the websocket by dispatching an action to the store that the middleware intercepts, and you can take messages received from the websocket and turn them into Redux actions.